# Optimising apply(X,c(1,2),min,100)

Tags: r, function, apply

I'm looking for a very fast version of the function `apply(X,c(1,2),min,100)`, where `X` is a matrix. 
I tried to use the function `with()` without success so far.

Comment: my duplicate-close-hammer is assuming that `X` is a matrix.  If it's a multidimensional array (which seems a less likely possibility), edit your question to reflect that fact (ideally with a reproducible example) and high-rep users can vote to re-open it.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for bothering.

Comment: pmin is working so great thank you!